# Showing data when multiple objects exist in JSON URL

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSON File, showing the following:

```
  {
    "version": 2,
    "locations": [{
        "id": "750",
        "geo": {
            "name": "Lord Howe Island",
            "state": "Lord Howe Island",
            "country": {
                "id": "au",
                "name": "Australia"
            },
            "latitude": -31.557,
            "longitude": 159.086
        },
        "astronomy": {
            "objects": [{
                "name": "moon",
                "days": [{
                    "date": "2018-09-05",
                    "events": [],
                    "moonphase": "waningcrescent"
                }]
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

I am attempting to show in a TextView the following fields:

name "Lord Howe Island"
latitude "-31.557"
longitude "159.086"
moonphase "waningcrescent"

I have tried the following:

```
JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);
        for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++){
            JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
            singleParsed = "Name:" + JO.get("name") + "\n" +
                           "Latitude:" + JO.get("latitude") + "\n" +
                           "Longitude:" + JO.get("longitude") + "\n" +
                           "Phase: " + JO.get("moonphase") + "\n";

        }
```

But unfortunately I do not receive any results.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks very much for any help.

Edit - Full Code for assistance.

```
public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
String data = "";
String dataParsed = "";
String singleParsed = "";
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL("example.com"); //Replace with API URL

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        while (line != null){
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            data = data + line;
        }

        JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);
        for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
            JSONObject geo = JO.getJSONObject("geo");
            JSONObject astronomy = JO.getJSONObject("astronomy");
            singleParsed = "Name:" + geo.get("name") + "\n" +
                    "Latitude:" + JO.get("latitude") + "\n" +
                    "Longitude:" + JO.get("longitude") + "\n" +
                    "Phase: " + astronomy.get("moonphase") + "\n";
        }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    MainActivity.fetcheddata.setText(this.data);


}
```

}

Comment: Did you get any stacktrace or error? When you 'setText' to your TextView?

Comment: No I did not. I used "MainActivity.fetcheddata.setText(this.data)", which returns EVERYTHING in the Json, including tags. However, I now want to pick what I show, like how I mentioned in the question. So I used "dataParsed = dataParsed + singleParsed;" and " MainActivity.fetcheddata.setText(this.dataParsed);" to show, but nothing shows from the JSON. I receive no errors, just no data.

Answer (score 0):

Your json parsing is wrong.First of all there is just one object in your json array there is no need of the for loop. You can access it directly using **0th** index.

Second

```
            JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
```

This line just gave you the 1st json object inside the array. You have to do one more step to fetch the name.

```
JSONObject geo=JO.getJSONObject("geo");
```

Now fetch the name from geo object.

```
"Name:" + geo.getString("name") + "\n"
```

Also remember your **moonphase** string is part of different array. So you need to parse that accordingly
You have to get value of the type defined in your json.For eg. for getting string type it will be

```
jsonObject.getString("key");
```

for integer it will be

```
jsonObject.getInt("key")
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately. Please see the updated post for additional code. I still only receive data using "data" in the setText field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 JSONObject data=new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray JA = data.getJSONArray("locations");
    for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++){
    JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
    JSONObject geo=JO.getJSONObject("geo");
    JSONObject astronomy=JO.getJSONObject("astronomy");
    singleParsed = "Name:" + geo.get("name") + "\n" +
            "Latitude:" + JO.get("latitude") + "\n" +
            "Longitude:" + JO.get("longitude") + "\n" +
            "Phase: " + astronomy.get("moonphase") + "\n";
```

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. I only receive data when using "MainActivity.fetcheddata.setText(this.data);".

Answer (score 0):

instead of parsing JSON on your own use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

> Gson gson= new Gson();
>
> YourBeanClass yourBeanClass  gson.fromJson(jsonString,YourBeanClass.class)

[Json to Java POJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

From above you can get as Bean class just use it to parse your Json.Using POJO to parse json is easy and less vulnerable to error/exception.

For your Json i tried getting the bean object and tried parsing.

And your code will also be more readable:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL("example.com"); //Replace with API URL

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        while (line != null){
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            data = data + line;
        }

        Gson gson= new Gson();
        YourBeanClass yourBeanClass  gson.fromJson(jsonString,YourBeanClass.class)

      //get and set all your data here from your bean
       String country=yourBeanClass.getCountry()
        


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;
}
```

Comment: there are special plugin in AS to convert JSON to kotlin data class.